# What does this error mean: "No such field found: field java.lang.String size" in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

The script in question is this:

```
propList = readFile("/opt/cvsdirs/loadbuild/jenkins/slave/workspace/ccsmp_branches_features_CRE-442/$BRANCH_NAME/tools/svn.properties").split('\n') as List
        def propListClean = []
        for (i=0; i < propList.size; i++) {
          if (propList[i].contains('=')) {
            propListClean += propList[i]
          }
        }
        print(propListClean)
```

The console output is:

```
org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException: No such field found: field java.lang.String size
```

I checked but there are no pending in-script approvals.

Why is this happening?

Comment: So that error message looks somewhat strange, but in essence your `propList` is casting as a String instead of a List, and there is no class member method `size` for String. Have you tried directly iterating on the lines of the file instead?

Comment: No haven't done that yet I could give it a go but the problem is that I have to keep this format.

Answer (score 0):

```
def propListClean = readFile("...").readLines().findAll{it.contains('=')}
```